# How to resolve NON-FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR in CVI/Labwindows

Tags: cvi

It says "the call back function function specified in uir is not a known function. If you are using the external compiler,you must include all the uir callbacks objects or source file in the executable or DLL".  Am getting this error,how to resolve this issue.
Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and provide the code that leads to the error.

Answer (score 0):

See [how to use callback functions](http://www.howtocvi.net/2011/11/how-to-use-callback-functions-part-1.html).
Normally when you have defined a callback **YOURCBK** for a control in your **YOURUIR**.UIR, then the prototype of the callback should be automatically generated in a corresponding **YOURUIR**.h as follow:

```
/* Callback Prototypes: */ 
int  CVICALLBACK YOURCBK(int panel, int control, int event, void *callbackData, int eventData1, int eventData2);
```

Then all you have to do is to define the implementation of this callback in a c file and include it in the project:

```
int CVICALLBACK YOURCBK(int panel, int control, int event,
        void *callbackData, int eventData1, int eventData2)
{
    switch (event)
    {
        case EVENT_COMMIT:
            MessagePopup("Hooray", "You clicked me!");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```